# How can I get all child classes in BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.select('div.GMBodyMid')
table = tables[0]
table_html = str(table)
table_df_list = pd.read_html(table_html)
table_df = table_df_list[0]
data = pd.DataFrame(table_df)
```

I tried to get all classes but only 'GMPageFirst' class gotten three times.
How can I get all classes in 'GMBodyMid' class?[image]

Comment: Could you try: tables = soup.find_all("div", class_="GMBodyMid ")

Comment: I think it's extremely unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: @CarlosBazilio I tried that but I could extract only 'GMPageFirst' class

Comment: @AndrejKesely That web site needs sign in..

Comment: Please, list the whole html in your question.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
tables = soup.select('div' ,attrs={"class":"GMBodyMid"})
```